# Preallocating memory for Matlab tables without bookkeeping?

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I have switched from collecting the results of my Matlab simulations in structs to collecting them in tables. I'm very happy with this way of representing data, but I'm still not sure how to handle memory preallocation. If I just add rows to the bottom of the table, I suffer from the known issue of reallocating all of the variables included in the table in each iteration.

I can preallocate some arbitrary number of rows and at the termination of my script trim the table. But if I do that, I have to book-keep the number of rows that actually contain data. This number has to be taken into account in any operation on the table values, and this takes out the beauty of using this high-level object.

Is there a way to preallocate memory for a Matlab table that won't change the way the table behaves and that does not require external bookkeeping?

**Edit - clarification**

My question pertains not only to tables but to any Matlab variable class. I've been preallocating Matlab variables for years, it's frustrating that there's no effective one-liner that appends data without extra management. I would expect that at least the table object would include some smarter memory management solution. In my opinion, adding null rows in order to avoid reallocation has no place in scientific code (which should be as abstract as possible).

Comment: Would the same problem exist if you just have all the variables separately and only create the table once you finished operating on the data?

Comment: I'll still have to book-keep the number of 'filled' entries in each vector, it wouldn't be less cumbersome.

Comment: Although what you want is very sensible, it seems a little contradictory. If you preallocate I don't see how you can avoid the need to keep track of the number of used entries. One approach would be to preallocate with `NaN` values, and then use functions like `nansum` or  `nanmean`, which ignore `NaN`'s. But of course these functions ignore `NaN` by using some internal pre-processing (for example, `nansum` just makes them zero before summing). So you still have some kind of on-the-fly book-keeping

Comment: I wish a preallocation that does not affect the data stored. For example, consider a table t with 10 rows. t=t.preallocateRows(1000) would preallocate the memory required for 1000 rows but size(t,1) would stay 10.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own custom variable/table class to achieve what you are looking for, but to be honest, it is much easier just to work using the solution you have already suggested, namely, just using an extra counter variable to track where you are up to.

I understand your frustration that there's no 'cleaner' way, but in reality it's not that cumbersome, and any potential 'smart' solution is going to work well for some people and not so much for others, whether for efficiency reasons or otherwise. Plus, I guess in many cases the counter is already built into the loop:

```
A = zeros(2000, 1);
for i = 1:N
    A(i) = i^2;
    % i is the number of rows filled so far...
end
```